# Finding relations between Pronouns and Nouns in sentences

Tags: python, nlp, semantics, part-of-speech

I am working on an NLP project and I need the following functionality illustrated by an example. Say there is a sentence

> Tell Sam that he will have to leave without Arthur, as he is sick.

In this statement, the first `he` has to be tagged to Sam and the second `he` to Arthur. I work in Python. Any suggestions on what I can use to get the following functionality?

Comment: Requesting you to add code you have tried.

Comment: I haven't written any code yet as I do not understand exactly what I have to use. I have looked at nltk-chunkers to try and group pronouns closer to nouns by using the regular expression <NN><*><PR> which will match a noun followed by a pronoun. But this will not work in all the cases.

Comment: The example given here isn't great, as it could be read in multiple ways:

 - Tell Sam that Sam will have to leave without Arthur as Sam is sick
 - Tell Sam that Sam will have to leave without Arthur as Sam is sick

In fact, any sentence in this sort of structure has the same effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This task is called coreference resolution. In order to parse complex cases like the one you mention, you'd need to use a coreference resolution system, most of which (free/OOS) are developed in Java. There are several ways to easily use them from Python. One of the most well-know is this Standford CoreNLP wrapper: https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python

Answer (score 3):

Update:

There are now Python native tools with coreference resolution, such as:

- [AllenNLP](https://allennlp.org/models) by AllenAI.
- [Huggingface](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref) which is almost a spaCy expansion.
- [StanfordNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/) by Stanford.

These references were mainly retrieved from this nice RASA (a NLU based chatbot solution) tutorial: https://github.com/RasaHQ/tutorial-knowledge-base

Answer (score 3):

Like others suggested, this is coreference resolution which is an NLP active research topic.

Try the following code from huggingface(spacy):

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
import neuralcoref

neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp,greedyness=0.52)
doc = nlp("Tell Sam that he will have to leave without Arthur, as he is sick.")
print(doc._.coref_resolved)
```

You can adjust the greedyness of the algo to get more resolutions(replacements of pronouns). Keep in mind that increasing greedyness might give you incorrect resolutions, it will depend on your use case.